# Verbs that are used only in negative sentences or questions

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Some verbs are said to be used usually in negative or interrogatory (or sometimes conditional) sentences in some English-Japanese dictionaries.

For example, "care" which means "worry", "stand" which means "endure", "fault" which means "criticize" are that.

https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/fault

I have three questions though you don't necessarily have to answer all:

- Why those rules were created?
- What would you think if you saw those verbs are used in affirmative sentences?
- Can I use those words in affirmative sentences when you use those words in negative or interrogatory sentences and I wanna say yes?

Comment: _Usually_ being the operative word. Expressions such as "I don't care", "I can't stand it" and "I can't fault it" are very common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "rules" were never created, except when somebody noticed how people actually use the words and wrote it down: language rules are descriptive, not prescriptive (and language is very rarely consciously created). And "why" questions about language are almost always unanswerable. People came to use the words in those ways and not others.

The answers to your second and third questions is that they can be used in those senses affirmatively, but will sound odd and might not be understood without context. One context is that in your third question.

"You stand it" without context is likely to confuse; but a conversation that goes "I can't stand it!" "I'm sorry, but you'll have to stand it" is perfectly understandable.

Similarly "I will fault that book" is unusual and may not be understood, but "I can't fault the performance" "Well, I can: I will fault it until they stop doing it" is understandable. It's still not standard, though.